# Malformatted decimal giving wrong error

Tags: python, decimal

I have this snippet:

```
Decimal('5,1')
```

What it should raise (verified on Python 3.6.5):

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '5,1'
```

What I get in a certain Python 3.6.1 environment:

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Nobody will be able to reproduce this, because nobody else has this "certain environment".

Comment: Actually, @ChristophTerasa I've managed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry, mea culpa, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems indeed a bug that was fixed in releases between 3.6.1 and 3.6.5.

My machine has 3.6.1 installed and I could reproduce it:

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('5,1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
>>>
```

I couldn't spot a specific fix for it in their [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-6-5-final), but upgrading should do it for you.